# Spring: Using "Lookup method injection" for my ThreadFactory looks not scalable

Tags: java, spring, prototype, factory

We're building a `ThreadFactory` so everytime a singleton controller needs a new thread, i get a new instance everytime.

Looking at [Lookup method injection](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.0/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-method-injection) looks good but what if we have multiple thread classes? I like the fact that i can autowire my threadBeans.

like:

```
public abstract class ThreadManager {
        public abstract Thread createThreadA();
        public abstract Thread createThreadB();
}
```

and config:

```
<bean id="threadManager" class="bla.ThreadManager" singleton="true">
    <lookup-method name="createThreadA" bean="threadA" />
    <lookup-method name="createThreadB" bean="threadB"/>
</bean>
<!-- Yes! i can autowire now :)-->
<bean id="threadA" class="bla.ThreadA" singleton="false" autowire="byType">
<bean id="threadB" class="bla.ThreadB" singleton="false" autowire="byType">
```

and usage:

```
threadManager.createThreadA();
```

**Question**: I don't want to create an abstract "create" method for every new threadclass.

Is it possible to make this generich like:

```
threadManager.createThread(ThreadA.class);
```

I also looked at `ServiceLocatorFactoryBean` but for multiple classes i have to pass the bean name (not type safe).
Thank you

Comment: There's really no reason for modern Java apps to create their own threads. A `java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService` is a much easier way to handle async processing.

Comment: Yeah I looked at 'TaskExecutor' but I may not use it. Legacy code.

Comment: what is the difference between the various thread classes? Do they run different runnables? Wouldn't passing the runnable be easier then?
If not, then your approach with a `Class<? extends Thread>` should work indeed...

Comment: @Christopher: Yes runnables makes sense but we need the Thread for the isAlive() method. Yeah i'm into legacy code here...

Comment: @Michael: I was thinking about passing a Runnable to the Factory and getting a Thread back, that works on this Runnable. Then you do not need several Thread classes

Comment: @Christopher: Thanks for that suggestion. But for now i just have these Thread classes, and i need some kind of prototype factory.:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to do that automatically. And if you don't want to use `ExecutorService`, as suggested, you you can achieve this manually, if it is such a problem for you (but I don't think it is)

- make your `threadManager` implement `ApplicationContextAware` or `BeanFactoryAware`, thus obtaining the application context / bean factory
- in your `createThread(..)` method use the context/factory obtained above to get an instance of the thread bean (which should be of scope `prototype` of course)

Comment: Thank you but that's not the problem i described in my question.

Comment: You want me not using IOC and call a getbean()?

Comment: Yes. But that's what the lookup-method is actually doing anyway. It will just be your custom lookup-method

Comment: This way i also don't have type safety. i'd like to pass the class, but getbean() wants a bean name.

Comment: look around the other methods there - you can list all beans and get the one with the appropriate class.